# CKEDITOR - inserting into custom tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use custom tags in my CKEDITOR and my problem is that when I try to paste between custom tag, i throws error: `TypeError: E[u.getName(...)] is undefined`

default source in my CKEDITOR is always `<custom_tag><p></p></custom_tag>`

I need to paste text between custom tags to make it like `<custom_tag><p>Some text...</p></custom_tag>`

When I try to paste text without html or simple text like `<p>Some text...</p>`, it works. But when text contains more html tags like `<p>Some text..</p><p>Some other text..</p>`, it throws error above.

In config i have these settings:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

EDIT: added [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLorz4eb/). Try to paste some formatted text, it won't work.

Any clues how to solve this?

I need to use custom tags in this case, so removing them is not an option.

Comment: Can you make a working snippet of your code?

Comment: Added JSFiddle link to original post